# Editing a dataframe with several points in time with ifelse

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have this dataframe:

```
id <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
x <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y <- c(NA, 5, 5, 5, NA, 5)
t <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)

df <- data.frame(id, t, x, y)
df

  id t x  y
1  1 1 0 NA
2  1 2 0  5
3  2 1 0  5
4  2 2 0  5
5  3 1 0 NA
6  3 2 0  5
```

`id` and `t` refer to three cases at two points in time. `x` and `y` are some random values.
Now I want to add 9 to vector `x` in `t = 2`, but only if `y` in `t = 1` is NA.

The output should look like that:

```
> df
  id t x  y
1  1 1 0 NA
2  1 2 9  5
3  2 1 0  5
4  2 2 0  5
5  3 1 0 NA
6  3 2 9  5
```

I am grateful for any help. In addition, a solution with ifelse would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you want to do this by group.

Here for each `id` we add `x + 9` at `t ==2` if `y` at `t==1` is `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(x = ifelse(is.na(y[t==1]) & t == 2, x + 9, x))

#    id     t     x     y
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    1.    1.    0.   NA 
#2    1.    2.    9.    5.
#3    2.    1.    0.    5.
#4    2.    2.    0.    5.
#5    3.    1.    0.   NA 
#6    3.    2.    9.    5.
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid <dbl> in the output?

Comment: @C.F. do you mean in the display? You could convert it back to `data.frame`. Try `df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(x = ifelse(is.na(y[t==1]) & t == 2, x + 9, x)) %>% data.frame()`

Comment: It turned out that my example was too simple. Nevertheless, I do not want to open a new question, so I ask here: not just a number should be added to x (like the `9`). The cases are to be changed using a more complex procedure. Example: `f <- id + 1` and then `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(x = ifelse(is.na(y[t==1]) & t == 2, f, x))`. In this case, `x` in case 1 (`id = 1`, `t  = 2`) should be `3` and `x` in case 3 (`id = 3`, `t = 2`) should be `5`. In fact, this wont work with the current solution. That was not considered in the original question but I would be happy about a solution.

Comment: @C.F. should the output be 2 and 4 for id 1 and 3 respectively? Not sure if I understood you correctly, but do you want something like `df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(x = ifelse(is.na(y[t==1]) & t == 2, id + 1, x))` ? Or if you want to use a function we could do `f <- function(id) id + 1` and then `df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(x = ifelse(is.na(y[t==1]) & t == 2, f(id), x))`

Answer (score 2):

You can create the idvar and selected id which met the conditions, then assign the value.

```
idvar = df$id[df$t == 1 & is.na(df$y)]
df$x[df$id %in% idvar & df$t == 2] = +9
df
  id t x  y
1  1 1 0 NA
2  1 2 9  5
3  2 1 0  5
4  2 2 0  5
5  3 1 0 NA
6  3 2 9  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there will always be two time points and they are ordered as in the example, here would be the ifelse:

```
df$x <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(z) ifelse(df$t[z] == 2 & is.na(df$y[z-1]) == TRUE
   , df$x[z]+9, df$x[z])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[shift(t == 1 & is.na(y)) & t == 2, x := x + 9, id]
df
#   id t x  y
#1:  1 1 0 NA
#2:  1 2 9  5
#3:  2 1 0  5
#4:  2 2 0  5
#5:  3 1 0 NA
#6:  3 2 9  5
```